# Ruby gem LoadError - rubygems/defaults/operating_system

Tags: ruby, operating-system, rubygems

I've installed ruby 1.8.6 p368 and gems 1.3.4 as well as required libraries like zlib, ssl or readline on my winxp sp3 box.
The problem is, when I now try to use some gem, I get the following error:

```
Exception `LoadError' at D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1112 - no su
ch file to load -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.
rb:31 - no such file to load -- mysql
```

Seems like it makes sense to start with fixing the missing "rubygems/defaults/operating_system" file. How can I do that? TIA

PS:
gem env is

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.4
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.6 (2009-03-31 patchlevel 368) [i386-mswin32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: D:/ruby/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: D:/ruby/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mswin32-60
  - GEM PATHS:
 - D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
 - C:/Documents and Settings/fluffy/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

Comment: Can you find "rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb" anywhere on your system? As of RubyGems 1.3.2 it looks like that file should be loaded, but only if it exists.

Could the file exist in the D:/ruby/... path but not the C:/Documents and Settings/... path, and context is switching from one to the other? ie, RubyGems checks D:/ path and the file exists, but then tries to load C:/ path and it fails. Just a guess...

This has more details: http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/04/rubygems-plugins

Comment: Please post the script you are running that generates the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Were you running using `-d`? If so, [this email](http://osdir.com/ml/ruby-talk/2009-11/msg01916.html) reckons that it's displaying exceptions even when they're rescued.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the mysql gem too.

Comment: here is what gem list shows


*** LOCAL GEMS ***

mechanize (0.9.3)
mysql (2.7.3)
nokogiri (1.3.1)

Answer (score 0):

The following error

```
Exception 'LoadError' at D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1112 - no such file to load -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
```

Can relate to either

1. a corrupt installation (check the **rubygems.rb** file and make sure it requires 'rubygems/defaults/operating_system'. If it does, check to see if it exists) or
2. you're trying to run a 2.3.x app while the server is still configured to using Rails 2.1.x

I hope this helps. If not, let me know.

Comment: 1. rubygems.rb really requires that file, but the file doesn't exist, I've found out that requing that file was introduced in gems 1.2.0, though the manual states "if that file exists". I've installed ruby by unpacking zip file I got from ftp.ruby-lang.org
2. I'm not trying to run rails app, in fact rails gem isn't installed at all

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried InstantRails? It has rails/apache/mysql in a nice package and worked out of the box on every XP box I tried.

I also install NetBeans as dev environment and just point it to InstantRails "bin/ruby" binary.